# Get all table elements in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, element

I have a webpage which looks like this:

```html
<table class="data" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3 by</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%"><a href="foo1">5120432</a></td>
            <td width="70%">INTERESTED_SITE1/</td>
            <td width="20%"><a href="foo2">foo2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td width="10%"><a href="foo1">5120431</a></td>
            <td width="70%">INTERESTED_SITE2</td>
            <td width="20%"><a href="foo2">foo2</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to put those two sites somewhere (interested_site1 and interested_site2). I tried doing something like this:

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
chrome.get("fooSite")
time.sleep(.5)

alert = chrome.find_element_by_xpath("/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").text
print (alert)
```

But I can't find the first site. If I can't do this in a for loop, I don't mind getting every link separately. How can I get to that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use a CSS query:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(2)")
```

Comment: A gentle word of caution! it will get u all the second column (td) in all the tables in your webpage. If your webpage has only one table, this will work fine.

Comment: it is better to use class names as anchors and it would work well. No single bullet for every edge case

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XPath expression to deal with this by looping over each row.

```
XPath expression: html/body/table/tbody/tr[i]/td[2]
```

Get the number of rows by,

```
totals_rows = chrome.find_elements_by_xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr")
total_rows_length = len(totals_rows)

for (row in totals_rows):
    count = 1
    site = "html/body/table/tbody/tr["+counter+]+"/td[2]"
    print("site name is:" + chrome.find_element_by_xpath(site).text)
    site += 1
```

Basically, loop through each row and get the value in the second column (td[2]).

Comment: This line seems to be bogus (never tested): `site = "html/body/table/tbody/tr["+counter+]+"/td[2]"`. Python 3.6.9: "`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`" (near "`]`").

Comment: And variable `counter` doesn't exist. And variable `row` is not used. And variable `site` is first assigned a string and then incremented like it is an integer.

Comment: Is the code completely bogus, and thus the answer?